# What is the difference between tmp and html in Go?

Tags: html, go

Im recently learning Golang and Im trying to create a website with Go as backend.
I done it correctly with a framework called `Martini` but I want to do it without frameworks.

Can anyone tell me whats the difference between html and tmpl? Because I want to call a page that loads a table with DB rows and I guess that first I have to understand what is the difference.

This is what I tried:

server.go:

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "html/template"
)

func main(){

    http.HandleFunc("/index/"), viewIndex)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}

func viewIndex(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("index.html")

}
```

I dont know what is the structure but I put the index.html on : /templates/index.html:

Contains `Hello World`

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None. Calling a file `index.html` or `index.tmpl` is up to the author. I personally prefer `.tmpl` as the files contain more than just HTML.

Some specific packages (like martini-render) might look only for certain file extensions, but nearly all should be configurable.

If you are just starting out I suggest reading http://jan.newmarch.name/golang/template/chapter-template.html

Comment: Thank you for the response, but in the website show me how the templates work, but How can I take an external .tmpl or .html? I have to create a directory called templates with the .html or .tmpl? I dont have this totally clear.

Comment: Also read this: http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/#tmp_6 - unless you post some code snippets though it is hard to help you directly. Update your question with what you have tried so far.

Comment: Run through the "Building a Web Application" article I linked. It covers how to parse templates, write them and render them. Right now you are parsing the file on every request and then doing nothing with it.